# Would questions about game-engine recommendations be on-topic, given they have clearly stated needs?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is a question asking for a recommendation of a game-engine fitting one's needs on-topic or off-topic?

There are SE formats such as [rpg.stackexchange.com](http://rpg.stackexchange.com) which allows for recommendation questions about game systems, which seems to be a similar case. What is GDSE's stance here?

*example:*

> I am looking for an engine to create a 3D, space game with 3 dimensional space and movement (*Homeworld-esque*).
>   I hence need an engine that doesn't limit my scene to a definite *ground* and/or *top*.
> What would you recommend me and why?
>   I am looking for answers based on your own experience or clearly stated facts & properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [help centre](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>
> ...
>
> and it is **not about...**
>
> - how to get started making a game
> - what language/engine/SDK you should learn
> - where free assets can be found
> - which technology is better
> - **which technology to use for your game idea**
> - what technology some particular game used
> - how to make (or start making) a particular type of game

So you're example question would be off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

For engine recommendations (and software ones in general), try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com which is a site tailored for this stuff. Note that they have pretty strict requirements for their questions; you must clearly state your needs/criteria, to avoid poll-like answers that devolve into popularity contests. But it looks like in this case you should be ok.

Personally I see a problem with your stated needs; you ask for a 3D engine that "doesn't limit my scene to a definite ground and/or top", but I'm not aware of any popular engine that has such limits, so to me it sounds like you should do a bit of independent research first.

Comment: It was more meant like a general example, not a definite thing.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T That is essentially the problem we've had with most people asking for technology (or specifically engine) recommendations. Most requests aren't so specific that one piece of technology is objectively better for it than others.